# NotFoundHttpException for image with long file name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some uploaded images I'm trying to display on my site, but they won't display I keep getting NotFoundHttpException for images. I'm using Laravel 5.3 . My folder structure looks like this

```
-app
   -public
      -img
         -courses
```

And the link to my images look like this

```
http://localhost:8000/img/courses/1515024545118897g0Kfv98iRsJDcfh44bbfjdf9h3gsDj
by3bjFi9vDgdId3sVF4hRsjhBbkebHvj545ccf3jjvcifD3gFsbdHdcyV54rSeff3hjuJ3hbJfsdhHvv
hshVkfHrcb548Ifg9n848v34hHJd7Ghd5fdrJfsjbVfVdi2Kffd72bfbjuI.jpg
```

The file names are really long but it worked when I wasn't using laravel before. If I use a link like this: `http://localhost:8000/img/courses/zoom.jpg` then it works. So I want to know if it is that the file name is too long. And is there a fix besides renaming the images with shorter names?

Comment: From where do you get such name? `1515024545118897g0Kfv98iRsJDcfh44bbfjdf9h3gsDj
by3bjFi9vDgdId3sVF4hRsjhBbkebHvj545ccf3jjvcifD3gFsbdHdcyV54rSeff3hjuJ3hbJfsdhHvv
hshVkfHrcb548Ifg9n848v34hHJd7Ghd5fdrJfsjbVfVdi2Kffd72bfbjuI.jpg`

Comment: is it the real file name?

Comment: Can you show us your route definition ?

Comment: It's stored in the `app/public/img/courses` folder, the images are uploaded and renamed like that

Comment: @RamyHerrira I haven't defined any routes for images

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Yes it is a real file name

Answer (score 0):

Your image url seems quite long so i think you should check for your apache server ***LimitRequestLine Directive*** .[LimitRequestLine Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline)

Comment: The files load on the page when I'm not using the laravel environment. I checked laravel's htaccess file and I didn't see a directive for LimitRequestLine

Comment: by default LimitRequestLine is set to 8190 bytes for example edit your virtual host file and add this line LimitRequestLine 16380